# Flutter: How to change size of sub-elements during a hero animation?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a Hero that has a sub-element I want to change size as part of the hero animation (in this case, I want its aspect ratio to change).

Here's my (stripped down) build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext build) {
  final aspect = expanded ? 1.3 : 1.0;
  return new Hero(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      new AspectRatio(
        aspect: aspect,
        child: // Stuff that creates a header
      ),
      new Container(
        child: // General descriptions
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Right now, the aspect ratio jumps between the two values.  My question is, can I animate aspect along with the hero animation, and have it slowly shift from 1.3 to 1.0 and back?

For a complete example (which also shows a weird overflow issue during a hero animation) see this Gist:
https://gist.github.com/fuzzybinary/74196bccecc6dd070b35474c4c9223d7

Comment: With this snippet i can't figure out what's the issue is. So post your full code and i'll try to give you a solution.

Comment: I've added a gist with a complete example.

Comment: I have the same problem even without AspectRatio. In my case it's two Icons with different size. I doubt that here is possibility to add scale animation, because widget size is set after transition (but I'm not sure).

Answer (score -1):

Since I'm in my house right now I'm not able to try out your code right now. But I have a working hero animation example with me. Try this out.

```
// main.dart class
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;
import 'package:flutter_test7/photo_hero.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test7/second_page.dart';

class HeroAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    timeDilation = 2.5; // 1.0 means normal animation speed.

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('Basic Hero Animation'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new PhotoHero(
          photo: 'images/flippers-alpha.png',
          width: 300.0,
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/second_page');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      home: new HeroAnimation(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/second_page': (context) => new SecondPage()
      },
    ),
  );
}

// photo_hero.dart class
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PhotoHero extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotoHero({Key key, this.photo, this.onTap, this.width})
      : super(key: key);

  final String photo;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final double width;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SizedBox(
      width: width,
      child: new Hero(
        tag: photo,
        child: new Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: new InkWell(
            onTap: onTap,
            child: new Image.asset(
              photo,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// second_page.dart class
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test7/photo_hero.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => new _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flippers Page'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: new PhotoHero(
          photo: 'images/flippers-alpha.png',
          width: 100.0,
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can get a hero animation working with a single layout child / image, it's when I'm combining multiple layout children that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jeff same problem with you. I made a question here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17924